# Python overwriting dictionaries while iterating

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I'm currently trying to write data to a json file. It's a dictionary with a nested dictionary inside. I'm iterating through jsonArray which is a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary has information for a particular book. The problem is that I created all of these keys at the highest level, but the nested info is always the last item in the data set. In the iterations shown, I know info_dict and rating_dict are producing the data I want, but they are being overwritten in json_dict by the last item in the data set.As you see the bookID at the uppermost level changes, but the data inside info and ratings is always overwritten.

[image].

I'm not sure how else to add to the dictionary without overwriting items. The book_id is unique each time, so I didn't think "info" or "ratings" would get overwritten further along the line.

This is what I have at the moment

```
def retrieve_popular_books(csv_in, json_out):
    jsonArray = []
    json_dict = {}
    info_list = []
    rating_list = []
    book_id = []
    info_dict = {}
    rating_dict = {}

    with open(csv_in, newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        for row in csv_dict_reader:
            average_rating = float(row["average_rating"])
            num_pages = int(row["num_pages"])
            ratings_count = int(row["ratings_count"])
            if average_rating > 4.50 and num_pages > 50 and ratings_count > 1000:
                jsonArray.append(row)
        
        for i in jsonArray:
            book_id = i['bookID']
            json_dict[book_id] = {}
            for k,v in i.items():
                if k != "bookID" and k!= "average_rating" and k!="ratings_count" and k!=     "text_reviews_count":
                    info_list.append({k:v})
                if k== "average_rating" or k=="ratings_count" or k== "text_reviews_count":
                    rating_list.append({k:v})
            for i in info_list:
                for k,v in i.items():
                    info_dict[k] = v
                    json_dict[book_id]["info"] = info_dict
            for i in rating_list:
                for k,v in i.items():
                    rating_dict[k] = v
                    json_dict[book_id]["ratings"] = rating_dict
   
    with open(json_out, 'w') as jsonf:
        json.dump(json_dict, jsonf, indent=4)

    retrieve_popular_books('books_data/books_v2.csv', 'books_data/books_v2_copy.json')`
```

What I've been getting. The uppermost keys change, but the info is the final entry in the data set we're pulling from.

```
{
    "863f3fd8-b4f5-43b8-8ec1-eb870faa334e": {
        "info": {
            "title": "Fullmetal Alchemist  Vol. 6 (Fullmetal Alchemist  #6)",
            "authors": "Hiromu Arakawa/Akira Watanabe",
            "isbn": "1421503190",
            "isbn13": "9781421503196",
            "language_code": "eng",
            "num_pages": "200",
            "publication_date": "3/21/2006",
            "publisher": "VIZ Media LLC"
        },
        "ratings": {
            "average_rating": "4.58",
            "ratings_count": "10052",
            "text_reviews_count": "201"
        }
    },
    "b343cec8-66dc-470a-8efe-47858e37aab5": {
        "info": {
            "title": "Fullmetal Alchemist  Vol. 6 (Fullmetal Alchemist  #6)",
            "authors": "Hiromu Arakawa/Akira Watanabe",
            "isbn": "1421503190",
            "isbn13": "9781421503196",
            "language_code": "eng",
            "num_pages": "200",
            "publication_date": "3/21/2006",
            "publisher": "VIZ Media LLC"
        },
        "ratings": {
            "average_rating": "4.58",
            "ratings_count": "10052",
            "text_reviews_count": "201"
        }
```

Comment: you keep adding *the same dict object* over and over again.

Comment: the json is not formed correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries and lists only store *references* to objects contained elsewhere. You're creating only one list object for either of `info_list` and `rating_list` and keep modifying it over and over again. Instead you need to create a *new* empty `info` and `rating` for each book. Also, you're using the list to only later build a dict; you can fill in the dictionary right away instead.

In general it is beneficial to *not* use the dictionary access and keep a reference to the needed structures in variables so you could do it in much more Pythonic fashion like this:

```
for i in jsonArray:
    # pop the bookID so that we don't need to ignore it later!
    book_id = i.pop("bookID")

    info = {}
    ratings = {}
    book = {"info": info, "ratings": ratings}
    json_dict[book_id] = book

    for k, v in i.items():
        if k in {"average_rating", "ratings_count", "text_reviews_count"}:
            ratings[k] = v
        else:
            info[k] = v
```

Comment: Thank you for helping a noob out! I needed "for k,v in i.items:" preceding the bottom if/else statement and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Nathan oops, yea I did not run the code :P I fixed the code in my answer to have the inner `for` too.